# Convert json string to date in dd-mm-yy format using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to bind data in a `dd-mm-yy` format for which I am using `json` to bind. Currently I get date as `2014-06-18T00:00:00`

I want in `dd-mm-yy` format. Kindly let me know how to do that.

Below is my code for the same.

```
if (getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE != "" || getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE == null) {
            $('#txtLaunchDate').val(getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE);
        }
```

my `getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE` = `2014-06-18T00:00:00`

Comment: Can you use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: @mersocarlin: if it works why not? just let me know how should I proceed

Comment: *"just let me know how should I proceed"* ... read the docs

Comment: Please also try searching before asking. There are 100's of similar questions here

Comment: You need to check for the existing answers on stackoverflow. There are plenty of answers that you can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see snippet

```js
var newDate = new Date("2014-06-18T00:00:00");
var day = newDate.getDate();
var month = newDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var year = newDate.getFullYear();
console.log(day + "-" + ("0" + (month)) + "-" + year );
```

Comment: in `getFullYear();` what if I want to show only `14`  in place of `2014` how to do that ?

Comment: you need to substring year value  year.toString().substr(-2);

Comment: yes done, also for month if i want to show like this `06` then ??

Comment: see edited snippet

Answer (score 1):

Using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```js
const date = '2014-06-18T00:00:00'
const format = 'DD-MM-YY'

console.log(moment(date).format(format))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: its conflicting with other js..

Comment: _its conflicting with other js_ is a bit hard to help you. Which JS? What kind of error do you have?